# Get the 1st working day of next month excluding holidays

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm attempting to return the 1st working day of next month which should exclude common public holidays - I decided to rely on `strototime()` as this can help and loop through dates. The issue now appears that `strototime()` can return "first day of next month" but fails at "second day of next month etc". Is there another way to return the dates or should I attempt to programmatically put together these dates?

Here is my script:

```
function getDODate() {
    // Dates to select:
    $dates = [
        "first day of next month",
        "second day of next month",
        "third day of next month",
        "forth day of next month",
        "fifth day of next month",
        "sixth day of next month",
        "seventh day of next month"
    ];

    // public holidays:
    $publicHolidays = ['0101', '0501'];

    foreach ($dates AS $day) {
        // Get the dates for check:
        $monthDay = date("md", strtotime($day));
        $dayName = date("l", strtotime($day));
        echo $monthDay."<br />";
        // First, let's get the date to ensure it's not a public holiday:
        if (!in_array($monthDay, $publicHolidays)) {
            // Date does not fall on a public holiday, is it a weekend?
            if (!in_array($dayName, ['Saturday', 'Sunday'])) {
                // We've got a date that will work, return:
                return date("Ymd", strtotime($day));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check multiple times, as increasing the date from a weekend to a weekday might land on a public holiday. What if the entire week is public holiday, and the next date after that lands on a weekend again?

If it's a weekend, find the next Monday. If it's a public holiday, skip to the next day. Keep checking both until both are valid, then you're done.

```
$date = new DateTime("first day of next month");
$publicHolidays = ['01-01', '05-01']; // Format: mm-dd

while (true) {
    // format("N") >= 6 == Weekend
    if ($date->format("N") >= 6) {
        // If Saturday or Sunday, add 1 or 2 days. 
        // N=6 (Saturday), 8-6 = 2, get monday
        // N=7 (Sunday), 8-7 = 1, get monday
        $date->modify("+".(8-$date->format("N"))." days");
    } elseif (in_array($date->format("m-d"), $publicHolidays)) {
        // This day is a public holiday! Add one.
        $date->modify("+1 day");
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/tlDMl

Answer (score -1):

Is it pretty? No. Will it work? You bet!

```
function getDODate() {
    // public holidays:
    $publicHolidays = ['0101', '0501'];
    // Iterate from the 1st - 7th for dates:
    for($i=1;$i<=7;$i++) {
        // Day of the month:
        $day = "0".$i;
        // Next Actual month:
        $month = date("m",strtotime("next month"));
        // DayMonth to compare for public holidays:
        $monthDay = $month.$day;
        // Fulldate (this will be returned:
        $fullDate = date("Y").$monthDay;
        // Day Name of the fullDate about:
        $dayName = date("l", strtotime($fullDate));
        // First, let's get the date to ensure it's not a public holiday:
        if (!in_array($monthDay, $publicHolidays)) {
            // Date does not fall on a public holiday, is it a weekend?
            if (!in_array($dayName, ['Saturday', 'Sunday'])) {
                // We've got a date that will work, return:
                return $fullDate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly a very hypothetical scenario for your needs, but this won't quite work if the first 7 days are considered either a weekend or public holiday. https://3v4l.org/fLvq1 You'd need something more recursive.